# JqPlot Horizontal Bar Overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am trying to create horizontal chart with jQplot and tried all the options. However, the bars are overlapping.

Please let me know if I missed anything.

```
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        barDirection: 'horizontal',
        barMargin: 30,barWidth: 25
    }               
},
series: series,
axes: {
    yaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: ticks,
        barMargin: 30
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle here: [jqPlot Horizontal Bar Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/cf6xd9o2/)
I used the above snippet, and it worked fine for me.
BTW, the `series: series` isn't defined in the snippet that you provided.

And the bars aren't overlapping in my case. Check the fiddle. Is your code something similar to the one in the fiddle. If not, then please update/post some more code, which will help us investigate the issue.

Hope it helps.